# #import "directory/file.h" not found from a cross directory

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, compilation, header-files

I am trying to import a header from a file across sibling directories.

The project looks like this:

```
Project.xcodeproj
  SubdirA
    FileA.h
    FileA.m
  SubdirB
    FileB.h
    FileB.m
```

In `SubdirA/FileA.m`:

```
#import "FileA.h"
#import "SubdirB/FileB.h"
```

I can only get this to work if I change the second #import to:

```
#import "../SubdirB/FileB.h"
```

I have the parent directory of SubdirA and SubdirB in `USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` as `$(PROJECT_DIR)`. My understanding is that the #import "SubdirB/FileB.h" should be attempted from both FileA's directory and each of the paths in `USER_SEARCH_PATHS`. So this should work.

What's the proper way of fixing this? I've hit this in the past, but can never remember how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

In `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` you will need to add `../SubdirB` . for changing this you will need to go in project's build property and search for header search path. then add this path. it will work.

Thanks,

Comment: Not enough. Tried USER_SEARCH_PATHS of $(PROJECT_DIR), .., SubdirB, $(PROJECT_DIR)/SubdirB. (All at once, too.)

Comment: It was HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS, but I had to add $(PROJECT_DIR) ../SubdirB. Still, close enough. :)

Comment: you need not to add $(PROJECT_DIR) before ../SubdirB, Please try with just adding ../SubdirB only.

Comment: Tried, didn't work that way. Keep in mind I'm intentionally using a relative path in the #import. :)

Comment: what is your current import statement?

Comment: #import "SubdirB/FileB.h". The point of the question was avoiding the .. :)

Comment: and its not working when you set your HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS as ../SubdirB?

Comment: No. I needed to set it to $(PROJECT_DIR).

Comment: you are setting it separately,right? what error does it shows.